# Option value not get saved in the database

Tags: options

I'm trying to put up a simple plugin, but this Settings API doesn't give me a break.

I have one field registered in the settings page, but the values we enter don't get saved to the database.

[image]

Here is the code I've put together so far. Any help is highly appreciated

```php
<?php


if(is_admin()){
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_mysettings' );
}

function register_mysettings() { 

    register_setting( 'purchase-history-grid', 'num_of_columns' );

    add_settings_section(
        'plugin_section',
        __( 'The Grid', 'wordpress' ),
        'settings_section_callback',
        'purchase-history-grid'
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'num_of_columns',
        'Number of Columns',
        'show_num_of_cols',
        'purchase-history-grid',
        'plugin_section'
    );

  }



function my_plugin_menu() {
    add_options_page( 'Purchase History Grid', 'Purchase History Grid', 'manage_options', 'purchase-history-grid', 'my_plugin_options' );
}


function my_plugin_options() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }

    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Purchase History Grid by SolutionsW3</h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php"> 

    <?php

        settings_fields( 'purchase-history-grid' );
        do_settings_sections( 'purchase-history-grid' );

        submit_button(); 

    ?>

    </form> 
    </div>

<?php

}

function show_num_of_cols() {

    // get the value of the setting we've registered with register_setting()
    $setting = get_option('num_of_cols');

    // output the field
    ?>
    <input type="text" id="num_of_cols" name="num_of_cols" value="<?php echo isset( $setting ) ? esc_attr( $setting ) : ''; ?>">
    <?php
}

function settings_section_callback(  ) {
    echo __( 'Please configure the grid here', 'wordpress' );
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option value is not being saved in the database because, as you could see below, the registered option name is `num_of_columns` and **not** `num_of_cols`:

```php
// The second parameter is the option name.
register_setting( 'purchase-history-grid', 'num_of_columns' );
```

So make sure that you use the correct option name in your settings field callback:

- Use `get_option( 'num_of_columns' )` when retrieving the saved option, and
- Use `name="num_of_columns"` in the `<input>`

Comment: Many thanks Sally. There are so many variables going around and must have missed this important var. Stay safe. Thanks again. You saved my day, Unfortunately i'm unable to vote since my reputation is still too low.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, and it's alright about the upvote, but would you please kindly accept my answer? :) (just tick the check-mark next to my answer)

Comment: Hi, Done. thanks again :)